# Odoo: How to make a Generic Model that accepts other kinds of model (polymorphic)

Tags: python, odoo-12

[image]

Models `sale, purchase, return and transfer` all inhertit `transaction` model, while `inventory` has a Many2one field `transaction_id` field which is related to `transaction`, but even when using `inherit` in `sale` model and trying to save it's `id` in the `inventory` model results in an error
`psycopg2.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "custom_inventory" violates foreign key constraint "custom_inventory_transaction_id_fkey" DETAIL:  Key (transaction_id)=(27) is not present in table "custom_transaction"`

code

```
class CustomTransaction(models.Model):
    name = fields.Char(string='Name', readonly=True)
    date = fields.Datetime(string='Date', required=True, default=fields.Datetime.now())

class CustomInventory(models.Model):
    initial_quantity = fields.Integer(string="Initial Quantity")
    difference_quantity = fields.Integer(string="Difference Quantity")
    current_quantity = fields.Integer(string="Current Quantity")
    transaction_id = fields.Many2one("custom.transaction", string="Quantity Reference")

class CustomSale(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.sale'
    _inherit = 'custom.transaction'
    user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Salesperson')
    branch_id = fields.Many2one('custom.branch', string="Branch")
    customer_id = fields.Many2one('custom.customer', string='Client')
    init_qty = fields.Integer("init_qty")
    diff_qty = fields.Integer("diff_qty")
    curr_qty = fields.Integer("curr_qty")

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        result = super(CustomSale, self).create(vals)
        values = {
            'init_qty': vals['init_qty'],
            'diff_qty': vals['diff_qty'],
            'curr_qty': vals['curr_qty'],
            'transaction_id': result.id,
        }
        new_quantity = self.env['custom.inventory'].create(values)
        return result
```

Comment: Use `AbstractModel` for abstract super classes meant to be shared by multiple inheriting models

Answer (score 0):

Use **`_inherit`** and **`_inherits`** functionalities of odoo.

that will satisfy your conditions I think.